# Como podría resumir este código JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function resizeMap(idMap, sizeParameter1, sizeParameter2, sizeParameter3, sizeParameter4){
    var $idMap= $(idMap);
    var $sizeParameter1= $(sizeParameter1);
    var $sizeParameter2= $(sizeParameter2);
    var $sizeParameter3= $(sizeParameter3);
    var $sizeParameter4= $(sizeParameter4);
    var $widthVentana= $ventana.width();

    if ($widthVentana < 768) {
        if ($sizeParameter1.length) {
            var $mSize1 = $(sizeParameter1).height();
        }
        else {
            var $mSize1= 0;
        }
        if ($sizeParameter2.length) {
            var $mSize2 = $(sizeParameter2).height();
        }
        else {
            var $mSize2= 0;
        }
        if ($sizeParameter3.length) {
            var $mSize3 = $(sizeParameter3).height();
        }
        else {
            var $mSize3= 0;
        }
        if ($sizeParameter4.length) {
            var $mSize4 = $(sizeParameter4).height();
        }
        else {
            var $mSize4= 0;
        }

        var $mResize= $ventana.height() - ($mSize1 + $mSize2 + $mSize3 + $mSize4);
        $idMap.css({'height':$mResize})
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca una breve explicación de la finalidad del código; alguna referencias *(comentarios en el código)* de que hace las partes significativas o medulares para entender que resultado se espera.

Comment: el código me lo pasaron sin explicarme he ahí el reto y también el calvario tener que refactorizar un código que no se exactamente que función cumple. Pero una ayuda con respecto a lo que hace el código es : re dimensionamiento de una ventana.

Answer (score 1):

Yo haria algo mas sencillo y menos confuso:
...

```
function resizeMap(idMap, sizeParameter1, sizeParameter2, sizeParameter3, sizeParameter4){
    var $idMap= $(idMap);
    var $sizeParameter1= $(sizeParameter1);
    var $sizeParameter2= $(sizeParameter2);
    var $sizeParameter3= $(sizeParameter3);
    var $sizeParameter4= $(sizeParameter4);
    var $widthVentana= $ventana.width();
    if ($widthVentana < 768) {

        var $mSize1 = $sizeParameter1.length ? $sizeParameter1.height() : 0;
        var $mSize2 = $sizeParameter2.length ? $sizeParameter2.height() : 0;
        var $mSize3 = $sizeParameter3.length ? $sizeParameter3.height() : 0;
        var $mSize4 = $sizeParameter4.length ? $sizeParameter4.height() : 0;

        var $mResize= $ventana.height() - ($mSize1 + $mSize2 + $mSize3 + $mSize4);
        $idMap.css({'height':$mResize})
    }
}
```

Lo otro que te diria es que sizeParameter1, sizeParameter2, sizeParameter3, y sizeParameter4 lo pasaras como un arreglo, de tal forma para que el codigo te quede mas limpio

```
function resizeMap(idMap, parameters){
    var $idMap= $(idMap);
    var $widthVentana= $ventana.width();
    if ($widthVentana < 768) {
        var totalSum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++){
            totalSum += ($(parameters[i]).length ? $(parameters[i]).height() : 0);
        }

        var $mResize= $ventana.height() - (totalSum);
        $idMap.css({'height':$mResize})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function resizeMap(idMap, sizeParameter1, sizeParameter2, sizeParameter3, sizeParameter4){
    var $params = [
        sizeParameter1,
        sizeParameter2,
        sizeParameter3,
        sizeParameter4,
    ]
    var $widthVentana= $ventana.width();
    if ($widthVentana < 768) {
        for(i in params){
            $params[i] = $params[i].length ? $($params[i]).height() : 0;
        }
        var $mResize = $ventana.height() - ($params[0] + $params[1] + 
        $params[2] + $params[3]);
        $(idMap).css({'height': $mResize})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizas esto sirva:

```
function resizeMap(idMap, sizeParameter1, sizeParameter2, sizeParameter3, sizeParameter4){
    var $idMap= $(idMap);
    var $sizes = $([sizeParameter1, sizeParameter2, sizeParameter3, sizeParameter4].join(', '));
    var $widthVentana= $ventana.width();
    if ($widthVentana < 768) {
        var sumaSizes = 0;
        $sizes.each(function() {
            sumaSizes += $(this).height();
        })
        var $mResize= $ventana.height() - sumaSizes;
        $idMap.css({'height':$mResize})
    }
}
```